# How can I extract audio/wav from an object with type buffer and data array in angular frontend

Tags: sql, angular, audio, blob, arraybuffer

I have ready had a blob in mysql[image: the picture is from workbench]

, and I have fetch the data from SQL to angular and console log them [image: the console]

, and the corresponding ts file [image: ts file]

All I want to do is to use  tag to play the audio in .wav, because when I upload those files to the server, the file is blob, but why I fetch the blob, the blob becomes an object? and I can't play the audio...[image: I want to play audio with the audio tag]